# Consume SOAP Web services from spring with security header

Tags: spring-boot, soap

I'm getting deprecated message for the bean Wss4jSecurityInterceptor. I'm using >spring-boot-starter-ws(1.4.7-RELEASE). spring-ws-security(2.4.4-RELEASE), org.apache.ws.security wss4j (1.6.9).

How to add the username token to consume SOAP services using Spring WebService Template ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry..Silly error..Need to upgrade to "org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor;"...wss4j2 instead of wss4j.

However still Null pointer exception " Received Fault message for request Exception=null.

Settled. The application message exception object isn't extracted properly from the SoapFaultClientException.. e.getSoapFault().getFaultDetail()